# Add serial number infront of dynamic SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query like `SELECT restaurant, sum(couponscount) as position FROM`coupons`group by restaurant order by rank desc` and I want to add serial infront of them so that I can know the rank of the each restaurant by its position.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,restaurant, sum(couponscount) as position FROM coupons group by restaurant order by rank desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Select rownum, * from (SELECT restaurant, sum(couponscount) as position FROM coupons group by restaurant order by rank desc);

This would work if u are using oracle DB.

Else

SET @rownum:=0;
SELECT @rownum:=@roenum+1 AS rank,restaurant, sum(couponscount) as position FROM coupons group by restaurant order by rank desc;